# How to add and paste a logo on a gtlf object

Tags: javascript

good evening friends

I'm working on a sportswear sales web application in which the user can customize their outfit in 3d.  For now I already know how to change the colors of an outfit and its parts and add patterns/textures to the outfit.  I'm stuck because I can't add a logo on the jersey, nor text to make the bib.  When I try to put the logo as another mesh it shows up on stage but is not stuck to the jersey like a texture.  When I try it as a texture it covers the whole object.

I use Threejs please help me I don't know what to do anymore

I would like when I load my gtlf object that my logo shows on the object as a texture and it uses a dragControls to be able to move on the jersey